# Unable to install Parquet capability with R-package Arrow 11.0.0 in Elyra notebooks?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, dockerfile, parquet, pyarrow, elyra

Hi I'm trying to prepare a docker image with a set of r-packages prepared. I'm runing into a problem trying to enable the parquet capability of r-Arrow 11.0.0

My approach is to install r-packages in docker build:

```
FROM elyra/elyra:3.14.3

RUN  pip install pyopenssl --upgrade
RUN  pip install jupyterlab-s3-browser 
RUN  jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyterlab_s3_browser

RUN  mamba install --quiet --yes  \
    'r-base' \
    'r-caret' \
    'r-crayon' \
    'r-devtools' \
    'r-e1071' \
    'r-forecast' \
    'r-hexbin' \
    'r-htmltools' \
    'r-htmlwidgets' \
    'r-irkernel' \
    'r-nycflights13' \
    'r-randomforest' \
    'r-rcurl' \
    'r-rmarkdown' \
    'r-rodbc' \
    'r-arrow=11.0.*' \ 
    && mamba clean --all

# tried with mamba install. but also using conda install as below
# RUN conda install r-arrow
```

When trying to use the r-Arrow package in Elyra/Elyra:3.14.3 notebook, the Parquet capability is not enabled although it is supposed turned on by default.
[Arrow capabilities 11.0.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNdzp.png)

When using the r-arrow='10.0.1' package the parquet is loaded in though.
[Arrow capabilities 10.0.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltVv9.png)

It seems that the 11.0.0 version has an incompatible dependency that is locked into the Elyra image.

Should I go about this in another way? I'd like to prepare an image with my company's basic requirements.